# как вывести путь файла из базы данных

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

в базе данных у меня храниться путь до картинки[image: введите сюда описание изображения], но при распаковке кортежа  `photo = str(*photo)[0].rstrip(",")`  путь изменяеться, добавляются лишние кавычки и слэшы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База сделана в sqlite studio
Подскажите как это исправить

Comment: А зачем вы делаете `str(*photo)`?! Обращайтесь к этому `photo` нормально, типа такого `photo[0]` или может `photo[0][0]` и там наверняка всё в нормальном виде лежит.

Comment: к сожалению все так же(

Comment: Очевидно, в самом значении в БД есть кавычки. А двойные обратные слеши это нормально, они отображаются только, когда вы смотрите на значение, как на строковый литерал. Возьмите а сделайте значению `print(...)` и слешей не будет, потому что в строке реально один слеш хранится, а при выводе строкового литерала (например в отладчике) слеш нужно экранировать, вот и появляется как бы дубликат.

Comment: Роман вы мой спаситель, благодаря вам я все понял, спасибо!!